# Unable to use logical operator within conditional statement

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, operator-keyword, logical-operators

I'm trying to write a conditional statement that will check while clicking the button, to check if at least one checkbox is checked.
So an example would be:

```
if (
    checkbox_delete.Checked = false && 
    checkbox_export = false && 
    checkbox_name = false && 
    checkbox_PST = false
)
{
    string messageboxtext = "Please check at least one of the checkboxes.";
    MessageBox.Show(messageboxtext);
}
```

I get error message saying: 
Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'
Can anyone help to figure out what am I doing wrong?

Ps. I also tried doing

```
 if (
    (checkbox_delete.Checked = false) && 
    (checkbox_export = false) && 
    (checkbox_name = false) && 
    (checkbox_PST = false)
 )
 {
     string messageboxtext = "Please check at least one of the checkboxes.";
     MessageBox.Show(messageboxtext);
 }
```

But I then get:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox'

Comment: I forgot to add ".checked" in the other checks.

Comment: Does that mean you solved your problem, and/or that you need to edit your post?

Comment: I solved the problem - Thanks.

Comment: you cannot set a whole object to false, you need to use "==" insead of "="

Comment: I'm voting to close this as being caused by one or more simple typographic errors.

Comment: 1. `=` is assignment, not comparison. 2. The result of a comparision is a boolean value. There is no need to compare boolean values. Just use the boolean directly, possibly with a `!` operator.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues with your current code:

1. As you've spotted, you need to reference the property `Checked`.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx for related documentation.
2. Also, instead of using `=` you should use `==`.  The first is used for assignment; the second for equality comparison.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4704401/361842 for more information on this point.  Try running the below code a console app or in LinqPad to see some of the odd results you can get when this is misunderstood:

### Example of Issue

```
bool something = true;
Debug.WriteLine(something); //returns true
if (something = false) {
    Debug.WriteLine("this won't show");
} else {
    Debug.WriteLine("this will show");  //this is output, which you'd maybe expect, but for the wrong reasons... 
}
Debug.WriteLine(something); //returns false, as we've reassigned it accidentally above

if (something = false) {
    Debug.WriteLine("this won't run");
} else {
    Debug.WriteLine("surprise!"); //even though we saw above that something is now false, because we assign the value false to something and then evaluate the value of something (rather than comparing `something` with `false`, finding them equanlt and thus returning `true`; so the above statement effectively reads `if (false)`
}
```

Outputs:

```
True
this will show
False
surprise!
```

... beyond that, your current code would also uncheck all of your checkboxes, as you're setting the checked property to false.

### Amended code:

```
if (
    checkbox_delete.Checked == false && 
    checkbox_export.Checked  == false && 
    checkbox_name.Checked  == false && 
    checkbox_PST.Checked  == false
)
{
    string messageboxtext = "Please check at least one of the checkboxes.";
    MessageBox.Show(messageboxtext);
}
```

An alternate method to saying "if all are false" would be to say "if none are true".  You may find that easier to read; but this is down to personal preference.  See below for an example:

```
if (!(
    checkbox_delete.Checked || 
    checkbox_export.Checked || 
    checkbox_name.Checked || 
    checkbox_PST.Checked 
))
{
    string messageboxtext = "Please check at least one of the checkboxes.";
    MessageBox.Show(messageboxtext);
}
```